# Create own DataSource with spring properties

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, properties, kotlin

I'm trying to create my **own** `DataSource` from the `application-prod.properties`.

Now I know my `application.properties` gets read, since it does pick up the `prod` active profile (shown in console)

In my `application-prod.properties` I have the following:

```
jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/myDb
jdbc.username=root
jdbc.password=root
jdbc.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
```

Now if I change the prefix, my console throws a compile-time error `Could not resolve Spring property placholder` which makes sense. This also shows that the compiler is actually checking if the `@Value` exists within the `properties` file.

```
@Component
open class BaseDAO(
        //@Value("\${jdbc.url}") private val url: String,
        //@Value("\${jdbc.username}") private val username: String,
        //@Value("\${jdbc.password}") private val password: String
) {
    @Value("\${jdbc.url}")
    lateinit open var url: String
    @Value("\${jdbc.username}")
    lateinit open var username: String
    @Value("\${jdbc.password}")
    lateinit open var password: String

    lateinit open public var datasource: DataSource;

    open fun getDs(): DataSource {
        return HikariCP.init(name="pool1", url = url, username = username, password = password)
    }
}
```

Now as you can see I tried passing the `@Value` in the constructor. But since I `extend` the `BaseDAO` in all my classes, it complained about the constructor being empty (`class SomeDAO : BaseDAO()`).

The problem occurring now is that my properties `url`, `username`, and `password` are not being initialized.

---

Is there a way to resolve the `properties` (without the use of `@Autowired` on all initializations/classes.)

The only thing I want is to read the properties from that file and use them, not looking for *'Spring best practices'* but for a **solution**

Answer (score 0):

Have an @Configuration class that contains initialisation for Datasource with those properties injected into it and then auto-wire that datasource bean in all your DAOs. Thereby, you do not have to inject those property values in DAOs.

Comment: But would this resolve the problem that the `@Value` is not setting the variable?